# How to prove this assertion? Do I need to use Inverse function Theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, inverse-function-theorem

Let $f:R^2\to R$ be a continuously differentiable function. Show that there exist a continuous one-one function $g:[0,1]\to R^2$ such that $f\circ g:[0,1]\to R $ is  constant.

Comment: Maybe you meant $g:[0,1]\to\mathbb R^2$?

Comment: Yeah, sorry. You are right.

Comment: Can you use Sard's theorem?

Comment: No, I can not use Sard's Theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f$ is constant, any $g$ will do. Otherwise there is a point $(p,q)\in{\mathbb R}^2$ with $\nabla f(p,q)\ne0$. Let $f(p,q)=:c$, and assume that $f_y(p,q)\ne0$. By the implicit function theorem there is a $C^1$-function
$$\psi:\quad x\mapsto y:=\psi(x)\ ,$$
defined in some neighborhood $U=\ ]p-h, p+h[\ $ of $p$, with $\psi(p)=q$, and
$$f\bigl(x,\psi(x)\bigr)=c\quad(x\in U)\ .$$
(This is expressing the fact that we can solve the equation $f(x,y)=c$ for $y$ in the neighborhood of $(p,q)$.) Now put
$$g(x):=\bigl(x,\psi(x)\bigr)\qquad(p-h<x<p+h)\ .$$
Note that $g$ is injective since the first component of $g$ is. – It is an easy matter to rescale the interval $U$ (or a slightly smaller compact interval) to $[0,1]$, if so desired.

Comment: Does this satisfy hypothesis of implicit function theorem. We need to have some $(a,b)\in R^2$ such that $f(a,b)=0$. What if there is no such $(a,b)$.

Comment: $0$ or $c$ – it's the same.